# Are beta only apps visible in Google Play Store

Tags: android-testing

I'm launching a new app and have tried to take steps to release beta versions of my app (prior to actual launch in Google Play Store).

Here is what I have done so far.
1. Uploaded a beta APK
2. Filled out enough meta data so that the portal allows me to 'publish' my app, so I have no production APK, just a beta APK.
3. Created a Google Group for testers to joined and have linked that google group to my beta list.

So my question is, I realize that members of the Google group I'm using for testing must be logged into the play store with the same account they joined my testing google group with.

Assuming they are logged into Play store with the correct account on the device, should they be able to see my beta only app in the play store?

The link from the developer portal entitled 'View in Play store' errors out with the message 'We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.'  Which makes sense to me as my app has no production APK at this point (this is run from my desk top, not the device).

So my question is, how should testers find my build to install it or is this an indication I've missed a step in prepping an APK for beta distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was pretty clear after sorting through the documentation.

There's a URL listed on the same screen where you manage testers.  You share that URL with testers (who have joined the group).  When they access that URL on their phone and following the prompting the will be able to see and download your app.

Works like a charm.